# Can I customize users privilege?

Tags: permissions, users, user-management, raspberrypi, privileges

I want to create a new user for my friend and let him access to my raspberry pi remotely from another city using SSH. I want to let him do what ever he wants except accessing respi-config other users files, managing users or and shutting down my pi. And as I mentioned before I want him to be able to do anything else like a sudo user.

What should I do? Is there anyway to do that?
Sorry I ask this question here, but I asked in raspberrypi.stackexchange.com but they couldn't answer that and suggested me to ask it here.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run `sudo visudo` to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file. There, or can specify which users will be allowed to do which sudo commands. It is recommended to view the man page before (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html)

The deny special things write an `!` in front of it.

```
YourFriend = ALL=ALL, !*raspi.conf*
```